# How to find the largest $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is $f(x)=\frac16 x^3-x^2+\frac32x-5$ with domain $(-\infty,a]$ invertible? without derivative

Tags: calculus

I am new to calculus and I am just learning about inverse functions. I was wondering how to find the largest value for $a$ such that $f(x)=\frac16 x^3-x^2+\frac32x-5$ with domain $(-\infty,a]$ is invertible.

Could someone help met take the steps to the correct value of $a$?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I want to do this without the derivative, since the function is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The derivative is $\frac{x^2}{2}-2x+\frac{3}{2}$. Use this to find the largest $a$ such that our function is increasing on $(-\infty, a]$.

**Added:** The question has been edited, and now the use of the derivative is excluded.  *General* cubics are not all that simple. One can approach the problem through the discriminant, but that is harder than the approach through the derivative.

However, our cubic is pleasantly simple. Throw away the irrelevant $-5$, and multiply by $6$ to get rid of fractions. We get $x(3-x)^2$.

For $x$ negative, we have that $x(3-x)^2$ is negative. As $x$ moves to the right through negative values, $|x|(3-x)^2$ decreases, so $x(3-x)^2$ increases. It follows that our $a$ must be positive.

It is clear that  our $a$ is $\le 3$. We find the local maximum in the interval $(0,3)$. By AM-GM we have $2x(3-x)^2)^{1/3}\le \frac{2x+(3-x)+(3-x)}{3}=2$, with equality when $2x=3-x$, that is, when $x=1$. The derivative was not used, but the argument is definitely more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

We may notice that:
$$ 3\cdot f(2x+2) = T_3(x)-14, \tag{1} $$
where $T_3$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). It follows that the leftmost stationary point of the RHS is at $x=-\frac{1}{2}=-\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$, so $f(x)$ is one-to-one on $\left(-\infty,1\right]$ but it is not on $\left(-\infty,a\right]$ if $a>1$.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is a continuous function, we need to find the largest value of $a$ such that $f$ is monotonic on $(-\infty, a]$.
Note that $f(x)$ and $6f(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 9x - 30$ have the same behavior.

Let $u = x - 2$ and $g(u) = 6f(x) = u^3 - 3u - 28$. For all $u\leqslant v$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
  g(u) - g(v) &= u^3 - v^3 - 3u + 3v \\
              &= (u - v)(u^2 + uv + v^2) - 3(u - v) \\
              &= (u - v)(u^2 + uv + v^2 - 3).
\end{align*}
$$
Clearly $u - v \leqslant 0$, and

- if $u \leqslant v\leqslant -1$, then $u^2 + uv + v^2 - 3\geqslant 0$, so $g$ is an increasing function on $(-\infty, -1]$;
- if $u = -1$ and $v\in [-1,1)$, then $u^2 + uv + v^2 - 3 < 0$, so the function $g$ is not monotonic on $(-\infty, b)$ for $v\in [-1,1)$.

We have showed that the biggest value of $b$ such that $g$ is invertible on $(-\infty,b)$ is $b = -1$, thus the biggest value of $a$ such that $f$ is invertible on $(-\infty,a)$ is $a = b + 2 = 1$.